# TabbedViewNavigator in mobile application

Tags: actionscript-3, air, tabbed-view

I have a Mobile Application  and trying to set a Master View that includes TabbedViewNavigator. This navigator includes two of ViewNavigator items those are Login and Settings.

Here is the main issue that I want to remove this navigator when the page is navigated to a third view(e.g Login navigated me to Home view).I just want to use navigator in a simple View, not both views of application.

I created an instance of MasterView and tried to `navigator.enabled=false` in Login view but, this returns null instance of navigator

> Is there any solution to remove this navigator in some spark Views? Do
>   I have to use in both views ?

Answer (score 0):

Any spark View has tabBarVisible property , and set `tabBarVisible = false;` simply.

Also use the `TabbedViewNavigator.hideTabBar()` and `TabbedViewNavigator.showTabBar()` methods to control the visibility.